# Using VS2013 to edit Script Components

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I'm running SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013, but when I try to edit a script component, it tries to launch Visual Studio 2012. Is there any way to force it to edit with 2013, instead, as I always get compatibility warnings with Visual Studio 2012?